# Excluding specific values from jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using Object Mapper and would like to exluce certain fields if they have specific values.

Assume that I have an object like following:

```
public static class Data 
{
    int id;
    int value;
}
```

And lets say the value is most probably will be 60. To reduce serialized data length I want them to serialized with only id's if the value is equal to 60. Is there a way to achieve this?

(BTW. I have tried to use 'ignore null' functionality by returning null for that exact value, but unfortunately that kills the beans reusability)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can writed custom serializer for this class. For example, your class could look like this:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = DataJsonSerializer.class)
class Data {

    public static final int DEFAULT_VALUE = 60;

    private int id;
    private int value = DEFAULT_VALUE;

    //getters, setters, toString, other
}
```

Serializer implementation could look like this:

```
class DataJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Data> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Data value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeFieldName("id");
        jgen.writeNumber(value.getId());
        if (value.getValue() != Data.DEFAULT_VALUE) {
            jgen.writeFieldName("value");
            jgen.writeNumber(value.getValue());
        }
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.CollectionType;

public class JacksonProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<Data> datas = new ArrayList<Data>(10);
        for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
            Data data = new Data();
            data.setId(index);
            data.setValue(index < 6 ? Data.DEFAULT_VALUE : index);
            datas.add(data);
        }
        System.out.println(datas);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(datas);

        System.out.println(json);

        CollectionType collectionType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(ArrayList.class, Data.class);
        List<Data> deserializedArray = mapper.readValue(json, collectionType);

        System.out.println(deserializedArray);
    }
}
```

Above program prints:

```
[Data [id=0, value=60], Data [id=1, value=60], Data [id=2, value=60], Data [id=3, value=60], Data [id=4, value=60], Data [id=5, value=60], Data [id=6, value=6], Data [id=7, value=7], Data [id=8, value=8], Data [id=9, value=9]]
[{"id":0},{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":4},{"id":5},{"id":6,"value":6},{"id":7,"value":7},{"id":8,"value":8},{"id":9,"value":9}]
[Data [id=0, value=60], Data [id=1, value=60], Data [id=2, value=60], Data [id=3, value=60], Data [id=4, value=60], Data [id=5, value=60], Data [id=6, value=6], Data [id=7, value=7], Data [id=8, value=8], Data [id=9, value=9]]
```